# Python can store different data types in a list or linkedlist

Tags: python-3.x, types

Python can store multiple data types object inside a list while we can not do the same for Java and C++.
What are the additional functions used by python to do that? And from where we can study about the same.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, you are allowed to do the same in Java. Just you need to have a more generic type.

For example,

In python you can write

```
array = []
array.append(1)
array.append("hi")
```

The equivalent code in Java would be:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add("hii");
```

This two pieces of code are functionally equivalent, however in Java we require a cast to the desired type we want when we fetch from the list. In Python, the type is deduced in runtime so we don't have to do any explicit casting.

Python is a fully object oriented language, and also dynamically typed. So most things in Python behave the same way. Maps, Sets, and more complex data structures allow you to mix value types easily. Even key types for collections can be a mix of different data types as long the proper contract is implemented. To learn more about the python type system, look here; https://blog.daftcode.pl/first-steps-with-python-type-system-30e4296722af

Answer (score 0):

I think everything in Python is dealt as an object and while we are storing data in Python, we are basically storing the references of the data. This may be the reason.